# Injecting strategy to POJO class in mybatis and spring

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have a simple POJO:

```
class MyClass {
  int a;
  String str;
  Strategy strategy;
```

}

where Strategy is an inteface which has a finite number of implementations that are defined as spring singleton beans. I want objects of this class to be retrieved from DB(for strategy field I have a simple ID field in table). So, I want to inject already present strategy implementation into the newly created MyClass instance depending on ID field in table. What is the best way to achieve this? I thought about discriminator, but it always creates new instances that are not managed by spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, I can offer next variant: 
create MyBatis `TypeHandler` for `Strategy` Type, where get the appropriate strategy bean from spring context.
I hope I have not forgotten anything.

Details:

```
MyClass {
private Strategy strategy;
}
StrategyA implements Strategy - "a" id in DB
StrategyB implements Strategy - "b" id in DB
```

1) spring-context.xml:

```
<bean id="strategyA" class="test.mybatis.inject.StrategyA" scope="singleton"></bean>
<bean id="strategyB" class="test.mybatis.inject.StrategyB" scope="singleton"></bean>
```

2) Create Spring context provider:

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        context = ctx;
    }
}
```

3) Add provider bean description to spring-context.xml:

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvder" class="test.mybatis.inject.ApplicationContextProvider"/>
```

4) Create StrategyTypeHandler:

```
@MappedTypes(value={Strategy.class})
public class StrategyTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<Strategy> {
    ...
    public Strategy getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        switch(rs.getString(columnName)){  //for Java 1.7 & above
            case "a":
                return (StrategyA)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(StrategyA.class);
            case "b":
                return (StrategyB)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(StrategyB.class);
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

5) MyClassMapper.xml:

```
<result column="strategy_id" property="strategy" jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="test.mybatis.inject.StrategyTypeHandler"/>
```

Run.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Spring-managed beans, could the Strategy interface be replaced by an enum?

-- edit --

Since you need Spring-managed beans, one option is to explore AOP since that enables Spring injection for objects created outside of the container.

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) in Spring's documentation on how to inject Spring dependencies into any object.

Comment: implementation of Strategy interface has dependencies on other spring-managed beans. I want to retireve MyClass object from DB and run some logic, which is encapsulated in Strategy object, but there is a bunch of implemenations of Strategy interface

Comment: Should I apply an aspect on MyClass's default constructor(which is used by mybatis to create object) call to inject spring-managed dependency?

Comment: Is it possible to apply an aspect to non-spring managed bean?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at

```
<context:spring-configured />
```

This will enable you to achieve what you want.

Comment: how in that case I can perform injection based on some condition(e.g. depending on already existing property value)?

Comment: SPEL might be helpful in this. This question might be of your interest  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805851/spring-settings-repository/16636022?noredirect=1#16636022